# on JpaRepository.save(Entity e) e have negative value as primary key in ms sql server database

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, annotations, spring-data-jpa, sequence

When i do JpaRepository.save(Entity e) the primary key generated with the help of hibernate sequence is saved as any random value generally starting from -43 or -42.

I am spring a spring boot project with JPA.

Below is my property file:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

This is my entity on which i am calling save. Sequence name - CPU_Responses_Seq is already present in DB

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CPU_Responses")
public class CPUResponses extends BaseEnity{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="CPUResponseSeq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CPUResponseSeq",sequenceName="CPU_Responses_Seq")
    @Column(name = "Response_ID", nullable=false,updatable=false)
    private long responseId;
```

This is my persistance config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"package path"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistanceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public Environment getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("entity path");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
        //that is optimized for the used database.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean(); 
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/CPUDB"); 
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }

     @Bean
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
            return transactionManager;
        }

}
```

I don't know what is getting wrong. Data is getting saved in DB but with negative primary key. My sequencer in DB have min value as zero so sequencer is correct.

Kindly help

Comment: how is going? did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the changes introduced in Hibernate in their sequence generator, try to add

hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
or
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false

note that the "new generator" is not compatible with previous version so start from a clean database to avoid issues.

Comment: I have tried but this did not worked. On the other hand i have added allocationSize=1 attribute in my @SequenceGenerator annotation and now it works fine. Thanks for help.